# Перекрывающиеся обработчики событий JQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!
Я пытаюсь повесить 2 обработчика событий таким образом :
1й - на первую ячейку*td* строки *tr*, а второй - на остальную часть строки. Строка может содержать сколько угодно ячеек.
Как мне лучше это сделать без попаболи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вешайте один обработчик на `tr` и проверяйте индекс `td` - если нулевой, то выполняете один обработчик, во всех остальных случаях  - второй.